# Encapsulation of multiple sub-system

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

We are looking to develop a offer calculation system which is backed by different kind of bid systems. Here are DB table structure for two bid system A & B,

```
BidSystemA - It stores list of Bids through Bid System A
-------------------
Id - int Primary Key
BidAmount - money

BidSystemA_Region - Each Individual Bid can have more than one region
------------------
StateCode - varchar(2)
Id - ForeignKey to BidSystemA

Make_Master
----------------------
Make - varchar(100) i.e Apple
Id - Primary Key

BidSystemA_Makes - Each Individual Bid can have more than one Makes
-------------------------
Make - Foreign Key to Make_Master
Id - Primary Key




BidSystemB - It stores list of Bids through Bid System B
-------------------
Id - int Primary Key
BidAmount - money

Feature_Master
----------------------
Id - Primary Key
Feature - varchar(50) i.e Has Camera, Has Touch Interface etc.

BidSystemB_Features - Each Individual Bid can have more than one features
------------------
Features - varchar(50)
Id - ForeignKey to Feature_Master

Screen_Dimension_Master
--------------------
Screen_Dimension - varchar(50) i.e 480x240

BidSystemB_Dimension - Each Individual Bid can have more than one Dimensions
-------------------------
Screen_Dimension - Foreign Key to Screen_Dimension_Master
Id - Primary Key
```

Now, I have sellers proving bidding through Bid System A & B. If a customer comes in to search to sell product then we need to present highest bid with help of both bid systems. We need to fire Query on Both system parallely and show highest Bid to customer.

I am looking design solution using SQL Server database features only.

I have two questions:

1. How can achieve parallelism in the database (Query multiple bid system at a time)?
2. Should I use View to aggregate multiple sub-system results and always query against view?

Comment: I think you need to tell us more about the different bid system tables and how they relate to each other. The question as it stands is just a bit too vague. If you can improve it then I'd be happy to migrate this to our Database Q&A site. Thanks.

Comment: Consider following tables
[code]
BidSystemA
--------------
[/code]